# Printf and fork: wrong ordering, even when wait(NULL) is used

Tags: c, linux, bash

So I am creating a very simple shell wrapper. The main process uses readline to read a line, it then gets parsed into a char*[], which then is processed by execvp. Fork is used to make sure the program continues after execvp runs. If the command ended with a &, then the mother process does not wait for the fork to finish before contiuing. If there is no & at the end then the mother waits for the child to finish.

Some code:
The main and input-accepting function

```
int main(){
    //Welcome message
    printf("Welcome to Bourne Shell Wrapper! Enter commands to run them, use ctrl+d to exit\n");
    while(1){
        //Prefering the complex readline over the easier scanf because of many functions that scanf does not offer.
        char* line = readline("shw> ");
        if (line == NULL) return 0;
        struct Command command = parseInput(line);
        if (command.params != NULL){
            if (!runCommand(command)) return 1;
        }
    }
```

Struct command:

```
struct Command{
    char async;
    char** params;
};
```

Function that runs the command:

```
int runCommand(struct Command command){
    //Fork, let the child run the command and the parent wait for the child to finish before returning
    //The child has 0 as childPid, the mother has another positive value. Thats how we seperate them
    pid_t childPid = fork();
    if (childPid == -1){
        printf("Failed to create child\n");
        return 0;
    } else if (childPid == 0){
        if (execvp(command.params[0], command.params) == -1){
            fprintf(stderr,"%s: ",strerror(errno));
            printCommand(command);
        }
        return 1;
    } else {
        if (!command.async){
            //This way the mother will wait until all her childeren are done before continuing 
            wait(NULL);
        } else {
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

So, here is the problem. The stuff works, when you do not want to go async:

```
Welcome to Bourne Shell Wrapper! Enter commands to run them, use ctrl+d to exit
shw> ls
debug  Makefile  obj  release  rpi-release  src
shw>
```

Just as expected: the mother process waits until the child has returned before printing shw> again. Then:

```
shw> ls &
shw> debug  Makefile  obj  release  rpi-release  src
```

Semi-expected: because the parent continues without waiting for the process, shw gets printed before the ls output. But then:

```
ls
shw> debug  Makefile  obj  release  rpi-release  src
```

Weird! The parent should wait until the subprocess finishes before reprinting shw>, but it prints before the child.

I have no clue why this is happening. Can someone point me in the right direction? For the record, without ever using the &, everything works perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment says:

```
the mother will wait until all her childeren are done before continuing
```

But that's not true. `wait()` waits for a single child, whichever one finishes first (including a child which finished before the `wait()` call.)

To summarize: when you execute an async command, you do not wait for the child to finish; when you execute a sync command, you wait for *a single child* to finish. In sum, you `wait()` for fewer children than you create.

When you call `wait()`, you know that you are waiting for a particular child, but you haven't told `wait` that, so it will just wait for whichever child finishes first. It's likely the child it ends up waiting on is the previously initiated async child, which already finished but whose status has not yet been reaped.

So here's an important principle: *Every* child must at some point be reaped. If you don't `wait(2)` for every child, you'll accumulate zombie processes: processes which are actually dead but still live in the OS process list because their statuses have not yet been retrieved.